# Error when calling another repo - 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first'

Tags: c#, linq, repository, iqueryable, datareader

```
 public IQueryable<Application> GetAppById(Guid Id)                     
 {
        return Repository.Query().Where(c => c.Id == Id).Select(c => c.App)
 }
```

I got this code above and it seems like it doesn't return right. If I call another repository in the DB such as Repository2.Query().Where(??code??). I got the error below.

**ERROR:**
{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}

---

However, when I change the return to ICollection<> it responses right.

```
 public ICollection<Application> GetAppById(Guid Id)                     
 {
        return Repository.Query().Where(c => c.Id == Id).Select(c => c.App).ToList();
 }
```

I debug IQueryable return, there is no error but I couldn't find find the data that it retrieves. The error takes place when you call another to the repo.

Comment: Do you open a DataReader on the same connection (or invoke any code that does) anywhere else in your program before this point? Are you perhaps trying to use a DbContext from multiple threads?

Comment: I debug IQueryable<Application> return, there is no error but I couldn't find find the data that it retrieves. The error takes place when you call another to the repo.

Comment: I have a feeling that the difference isn't in `IQueryable` versus `ICollection`, but the fact that you're calling `.ToList()`, which will fully evaluate your lazy queryable on the spot. Is `Repository.Query()` your own code, or is it a standard framework (e.g. EntityFramework))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is correct; you have allowed two commands to execute simultaneously. The first method shown returns a "query" - it doesn't actually execute *anything* until you iterate it - and is open until you *stop* iterating it. Indeed, the entire purpose of `IQueryable<T>` is to allow additional composition prior to execution. So assuming you are using `foreach`, the query is active for the duration of the `foreach`, **not** the call to `GetAppById` itself. So if you do the classic "N+1":

```
foreach(var row in SomeOuterQuery(...)) { // N+1, not a great idea
    SomeInnerQuery(row, ...);
}
```

then you are absolutely running multiple simultaneous commands.

There are three main fixes:

- run the first query *in full*, and then iterate the *results* - that is what adding `ToList` does: it moves the `foreach` to *inside* `GetAppById`
- enable "MARS" (Multiple Active Result Sets) - note: this is not advice, simply a "this will work" (but: not everything that works is a good idea)
- restructure the work to never need the "N" in the "N+1", for example by fetching the additional data *at the same time as the outer list* (multiple result grids from a single query, for example)

Comment: great.. this really helps.. ty